# How can I pass extra parameters to UDFs in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I want to parse the date columns in a `DataFrame`, and for each date column, the resolution for the date may change (i.e. 2011/01/10 => 2011 /01 if the resolution is set to "Month").

I wrote the following code:

```
def convertDataFrame(dataframe: DataFrame, schema : Array[FieldDataType], resolution: Array[DateResolutionType]) : DataFrame =
{
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  val convertDateFunc = udf{(x:String, resolution: DateResolutionType) => SparkDateTimeConverter.convertDate(x, resolution)}
  val convertDateTimeFunc = udf{(x:String, resolution: DateResolutionType) => SparkDateTimeConverter.convertDateTime(x, resolution)}

  val allColNames = dataframe.columns
  val allCols = allColNames.map(name => dataframe.col(name))

  val mappedCols =
  {
    for(i <- allCols.indices) yield
    {
      schema(i) match
      {
        case FieldDataType.Date => convertDateFunc(allCols(i), resolution(i)))
        case FieldDataType.DateTime => convertDateTimeFunc(allCols(i), resolution(i))
        case _ => allCols(i)
      }
    }
  }

  dataframe.select(mappedCols:_*)

}}
```

However it doesn't work. It seems that I can only pass `Column`s to UDFs. And I wonder if it will be very slow if I convert the `DataFrame` to `RDD` and apply the function on each row.

Does anyone know the correct solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just use a little bit of currying:

```
def convertDateFunc(resolution: DateResolutionType) = udf((x:String) => 
  SparkDateTimeConverter.convertDate(x, resolution))
```

and use it as follows:

```
case FieldDataType.Date => convertDateFunc(resolution(i))(allCols(i))
```

On a side note you should take a look at `sql.functions.trunc` and `sql.functions.date_format`. These should at least part of the job without using UDFs at all.

**Note**:

In Spark 2.2 or later you can use `typedLit` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit
```

which support a wider range of literals like `Seq` or `Map`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the intuition of currying!

Comment: I wrote a tutorial on how to use currying to create Spark UDF that accepts extra parameters at invocation time. https://gist.github.com/andrearota/5910b5c5ac65845f23856b2415474c38

Comment: Bravo, quite an insight into Spark.

Comment: Is it possible to register currying UDF with `spark.udf.register` in order to make it sql available?

Comment: someone put this in the documentation..!

Answer (score 23):

You can create a literal `Column` to pass to a udf using the `lit(...)` function defined in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`

For example:

```
val takeRight = udf((s: String, i: Int) => s.takeRight(i))
df.select(takeRight($"stringCol", lit(1)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I initially used `lit` as well, but it turns out that its performance is not as good as the other answer...