# Create a new column in a Spark DataFrame using a var with constant value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to define a new column in a Spark DataFrame using a constant defined as a `var`. I'm using Zeppelin - in the initial cell, it starts with

```
%spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
var year : Int = 2016
spark.read.parquet("<path/to/file>")
```

The file contains a column named birth_year; I want to create a new column named `age` defined as `$year - birth_year`, where `birth_year` is a string column. I'm not quite clear on how to do this when the input argument to a `UDF` is a parameter. I've done a couple hours of searching and created a `UDF`, but I got an error message whose principal part is

```
<console>:71: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
       spark.read.parquet("path/to/file").withColumn("birth_year", $"birth_year" cast "Int").withColumn("age", createAge(year, col("birth_year"))).createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
```

and a caret directly under 'year'.

I suspect that `$year` does not map into a variable of the same length as `birth_year`; I've seen the `lit()` function that appears to work for strings - does it work with integer values as well, or is there another function for this purpose?

I tried the following:

```
%spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
var year : Int = 2016
def createAge = udf((yr : Int, dob : Int) => {yr - dob})
spark.read.parquet("<path/to/file>").withColumn("birth_year", $"birth_year" cast "Int").withColumn("age", createAge($"year", col("birth_year"))).createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
```

Any suggestions welcome - thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass extra parameters to UDFs in SparkSql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546576/how-can-i-pass-extra-parameters-to-udfs-in-sparksql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `year` directly as an input to the `UDF` since a it expects columns to operate on. To create a column with a constant value use `lit()`. You can call the `UDF` as follows:

```
df.withColumn("age", createAge(lit(year), $"birth_year".cast("int")))
```

---

However, when possible it's always preferred to use the in-built functions in Spark when possible. In this case, **you do not need an `UDF`**. Simply do:

```
df.withColumn("age", lit(year) - $"birth_year".cast("int"))
```

This should be much faster.