# spark: scala - regex as argument for udf

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I am trying to check a column of a scala dataframe against a regular expression using a `udf` with an additional argument representing the actual regular expression. 
However, putting the regular expression into a `lit()` statement does not seem to be allowed throwing the following error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class
>   scala.util.matching.Regex

using the example code below. I'd expect an additional column "DMY" with Boolean entries.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.util.matching._


def dateDMY_regex(): Regex = """^[0-3]?[0-9][-/.][0-1]?[0-9][-/.](19|20)?\d{2}$""".r

def date_match(value: String, dateEx: Regex): Boolean = {
  return dateEx.unapplySeq(value).isDefined
}

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

var df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "31/10/2018"),
  (1, "01/11/2018"),
  (2, "02/11/2018"))).toDF("Id", "col_1")

// to test the function
// print(date_match("31/10/2018", dateDMY_regex()))

val date_match_udf = udf(date_match _)   //, lit("c")
df = df.withColumn( "DMY", date_match_udf( $"col_1", lit(dateDMY_regex()) ) )

df.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass extra parameters to UDFs in SparkSql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546576/how-can-i-pass-extra-parameters-to-udfs-in-sparksql)

Answer (score 1):

You can supply your non-Column parameter (i.e. value of `dateEx`) via currying in a UDF, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.util.matching._

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "31/10/2018"),
  (1, "999/11/2018"),
  (2, "02/11/2018"))
).toDF("Id", "col_1")

val dateEx = """^[0-3]?[0-9][-/.][0-1]?[0-9][-/.](19|20)?\d{2}$""".r

def date_match_udf(dateEx: Regex) = udf(
  (value: String) => dateEx.unapplySeq(value).isDefined
)

df.withColumn("DMY", date_match_udf(dateEx)($"col_1")).
  show
// +---+-----------+-----+
// | Id|      col_1|  DMY|
// +---+-----------+-----+
// |  0| 31/10/2018| true|
// |  1|999/11/2018|false|
// |  2| 02/11/2018| true|
// +---+-----------+-----+
```

However, for what you need, rather than UDF I would recommend using Spark's built-in functions which generally perform better.  Below is one approach using `regexp_extract`:

```
val dateExStr = """^([0-3]?[0-9][-/.][0-1]?[0-9][-/.](19|20)?\d{2})$"""

df.withColumn("DMY", $"col_1" === regexp_extract($"col_1", dateExStr, 1)).
  show
```

Answer (score 0):

I still have not achieved to pass through a regex. My work around is now to pass through a string and do the compilation within the function. As follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.util.matching._


def dateDMY_regex(): String = """^[0-3]?[0-9][-/.][0-1]?[0-9][-/.](19|20)?\d{2}$"""

def date_match(value: String, dateEx: String): Boolean = {
  return dateEx.r.unapplySeq(value).isDefined
}

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

var df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "31/10/2018"),
  (1, "01/11/2018"),
  (2, "02/11/2018"))).toDF("Id", "col_1")

// to test the function
// print(date_match("31/10/2018", dateDMY_regex()))

val date_match_udf = udf(date_match _)   //, lit("c")
df = df.withColumn( "DMY", date_match_udf( $"col_1", lit(dateDMY_regex()) ) )

df.show()
```