# Add column while maintaining correlation of the existing columns in Apache Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have a dataframe with columns review and rating in Spark Scala

```
val stopWordsList = scala.io.Source.fromFile("stopWords").getLines.toList
val downSampleReviewsDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT review, rating FROM ds");
```

I have written a function which will remove stopWords from a given review (String)

```
def cleanTextFunc(text: String, removeList: List[String]): String = removeList.fold(text) {
case (text, termToRemove) => text.replaceAll("\\b" + text + "\\b" , "").replaceAll("""[\p{Punct}&&[^.]]""", "").replaceAll(" +", " ")
```

}

How do I add another column "new_review" along with review and rating. The new_review should use cleanTextFunc() to get cleaned data for every row. cleanTextFunc takes two input arguments 1. text to clean 2. List of stop words to be removed from the text

Output should have Text | Rating | New_Text

Comment: Why not use the [`StopWordsRemover`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#stopwordsremover)?

Answer (score 0):

Just a few more lines

```
// Curried method to create UDF from removeList
def getStopWordRemoverUdf(removeList: List[String]): UserDefinedFunction = {
  udf { (text: String) =>
    cleanTextFunc(text, removeList)
  }
}

// Create UDF by passing your removeList
val stopWordRemoverUdf: UserDefinedFunction = getStopWordRemoverUdf(removeList)

// Use UDF to create new column
val cleanedDownSampleReviewsDf: DataFrame = downSampleReviewsDF.withColumn("new_review", stopWordRemoverUdf(downSampleReviewsDF("review")))
```

---

References

- [Passing extra parameters to UDF in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546576/how-can-i-pass-extra-parameters-to-udfs-in-sparksql)