# Supplying context for Spark UDF execution

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am working in Scala programming language. I want to hash the entire column of dataframe with sha2 and salt. I have implemented the following UDF which should take MessageDigest and input string which will be hashed.

```
  val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")

  val random = new SecureRandom();
  val salt: Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](16)
  random.nextBytes(salt)
  md.update(salt)

  dataFrame.withColumn("ColumnName", Sqlfunc(md, col("ColumnName")))

  ....some other code....

  val HashValue: ((MessageDigest, String) => String) = (md: MessageDigest, input: String) =>
  {
    val hashedPassword: Array[Byte] = md.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    val sb: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder
    for (b <- hashedPassword) {sb.append(String.format("%02x", Byte.box(b)))}
    sb.toString();
  }

  val Sqlfunc = udf(HashValue)
```

However the above code does not compile, because I dont know how to pass messageDigest to this function so I am running into following error

```
 <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ClassCastException: com...................$$anonfun$9 cannot be cast to scala.Function1
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? 
Also I am novice on cryptography so feel free to suggest anything you can. We have to use Sha2 and salt.
What do you think about the performance here?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass extra parameters to UDFs in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546576/how-can-i-pass-extra-parameters-to-udfs-in-spark-sql)

Comment: No it does not. the solution does not have a reference to dataframe. to be honest , i dont even know how to pass arguments in udf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MessageDigest` is not in your data. It's just context for the UDF evaluation. This type of context is provided via [closures](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-closures-in-scala-fp-examples).

There are many ways to achieve the desired effect. The following is a useful pattern that uses function [currying](http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-3-beginner-tutorial-using-functions-scala/scala-tutorial-create-function-currying-parameter-groups/):

```scala
object X extends Serializable {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

  def foo(context: String)(arg1: Int, arg2: Int): String =
    context.slice(arg1, arg2)

  def udfFoo(context: String): UserDefinedFunction =
    udf(foo(context) _)
}
```

Trying it out:

```
spark.range(1).toDF
  .select(X.udfFoo("Hello, there!")('id, 'id + 5))
  .show(false)
```

generates

```
+-----------------+
|UDF(id, (id + 5))|
+-----------------+
|Hello            |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Sim I have changed the code to         dataFrame.withColumn("ColumnName", udfHash2(md)(col("ColumnName")))   
  def udfHash2(md: MessageDigest): UserDefinedFunction =
    udf(hash2(md) _)


  def hash2(md: MessageDigest)(input: String): String =
  {
    val hashedPassword: Array[Byte] = md.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    val sb: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder
    for (b <- hashedPassword) {sb.append(String.format("%02x", Byte.box(b)))}
    sb.toString();
  }
it compiles but the final hash2 function never get called and hence does not encrypt frame. why?

Comment: Your code looks good. How do you know the function is not getting called? Rather than overriding `ColumnName`, add a different column. If the returned data is missing that column that you are somehow not using the transformation at all.